# How to Get Source of postback

Tags: asp.net, postback

if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
               //here I need  to know which control causes the postback
            }

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this posting

**[Get control name in Page_Load event which make the post back](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023533/http://geekswithblogs.net/mahesh/archive/2006/06/27/83264.aspx)**

Comment: It's often better to include the main code sample (as you had before your edit) in case the page you've linked to ever gets taken down, by all means keep the link to the article as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code from link "marked as Answer"( Just pasting code here so that we can save readers time):

```
private string getPostBackControlName()
 {

    Control control = null;
    //first we will check the "__EVENTTARGET" because if post back made by       the controls
    //which used "_doPostBack" function also available in Request.Form collection.

    string ctrlname = Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
    if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != String.Empty)
    {
        control = Page.FindControl(ctrlname);
    }

    // if __EVENTTARGET is null, the control is a button type and we need to
    // iterate over the form collection to find it
    else
    {
        string ctrlStr = String.Empty;
        Control c = null;
        foreach (string ctl in Page.Request.Form.AllKeys)
        {            

            c = Page.FindControl(ctl);               
            if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ||

                     c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton )
            {
                control = c;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (control == null)
        return "";
    else
        return control.ID; 

}
```